# Acces the correct button using this keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, ejs

i am having trouble selecting the correct button in my form. For example i have two items and i want to delete the one on the right and when i click to delete it always removes the one on the left;
I am shure the this keyword is not the correct one

Index.ejs

```
     <% service.forEach(function (myService) { %>
<form method="post" action="/service/<%= myService._id %>?_method=DELETE" name="del_form">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-del" name="del_btn"></button>
</form>
```

script.js

```
let delServiceBtn = $('button[name=del_btn]');
let delServiceForm = $('form[name=del_form]');

delServiceBtn.on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    if(confirm('Confirm delete')){
        delServiceForm.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: In the html code you have just one button defined.

Comment: With this line  <% service.forEach(function (myService) { %> i bring from my db the amount of buttons that i have stored there

Answer (score 0):

Add the `click` attribute to your `<button>` tag as,

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-del" name="del_btn" onClick="delService(this);"></button>
```

And write a new javascript function `delService` as,

```
function delService(buttonObj) {
   if(confirm('Confirm delete')){
     var btn = document.getElementsByName(buttonObj.name);
     btn.submit();
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Edited the js function.. Please revisit.

Comment: It dosen't reach this point because the form is submitting. If i stop the form for submitting and activated after it goes in a loop